# How to Dynamically get the path of a folder

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying to list Files Under a folder which is in my project path, I am working on `java Servlets`

I am doing It like this `File folder = new File("D:/Vivek/Touchpoint/MirrorImage/WebContent/Image/");` , I want to get this Path dynamic because In future I am going to Deploy it on some other system So have to take That path

I have tried `InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("D:/Vivek/Touchpoint/MirrorImage/WebContent/Image");`, but as of InputStream I am not able to loop after

I am doing whole code like this

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
             String DirectoryName="";
                File folder = new File("D:/Vivek/Touchpoint/MirrorImage/WebContent/Image/"); // Setting the path manually 
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); //creating an array to loop through
            //  System.out.println(folder);

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                 //   System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                     test=listOfFiles[i].getName();
                     System.out.println("Directory " + DirectoryName);
                  }

                }


}
```

[image: This]
Is my project structure

I have tried `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` but it prints `C:\Windows\system32\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Image");
File folder = new File(path);
...
```

Comment: Yup that works, I have small doubt regarding this question can you help me with some approach only, code I ll do it by my self

Comment: @viveksingh OK.

Comment: I ahve to make a JSON from the above data I ll get, If you are free than I can explain

Comment: @viveksingh you mean the list of files?

Comment: @viveksingh the directory tree?

Comment: Yup from that list of file I have to create array of objects